CPU: 6 PID: 112 Comm: kswapd0 Tainted: G OE 6.5.1 #69 when using do_madvise()
I tried to use do_madvice() and MADV_FREE in the Linux Kernel module, but sometimes the following errors were reported. I want to know:

whether I used the function correctly in this way?
how to avoid these errors?

int free(size_t start_va, size_t size, struct mm_struct* mm){
    start_va = PAGE_ALIGN(start_va);
    size = PAGE_ALIGN(size);
    int ret = do_madvise(mm, start_va, size, MADV_FREE);

    if (ret != 0) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Faulting in page at address %zu failed with error %d\n", start_va, ret);
    }
    return ret;
}

CPU: 6 PID: 112 Comm: kswapd0 Tainted: G           OE      6.5.1 #69

? get_swappiness+0x56/0x90

kswapd+0x1fb/0x3c0

? __pfx_kswapd+0x10/0x10

Modules linked in: mymodule(OE) isofs vsock_loopback vmw_vsock_virtio_transport_common vmw_vsock_vmci_transport snd_ens1371 snd_ac97_codec vsock intel_rapl_msr gameport binfmt_misc ac97_bus vmw_balloon nls_iso8859_1 snd_pcm intel_rapl_common snd_seq_midi intel_uncore_frequency_common snd_seq_midi_event crct10dif_pclmul polyval_clmulni polyval_generic ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel crypto_simd snd_rawmidi cryptd rapl snd_seq snd_seq_device input_leds joydev snd_timer serio_raw snd vmw_vmci soundcore mac_hid sch_fq_codel vmwgfx drm_ttm_helper ttm

kswapd0[112] exited with irqs disabled

Modules linked in: mymodule(OE) isofs vsock_loopback vmw_vsock_virtio_transport_common vmw_vsock_vmci_transport snd_ens1371 snd_ac97_codec vsock intel_rapl_msr gameport binfmt_misc ac97_bus vmw_balloon nls_iso8859_1 snd_pcm intel_rapl_common snd_seq_midi intel_uncore_frequency_common snd_seq_midi_event crct10dif_pclmul polyval_clmulni polyval_generic ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel crypto_simd snd_rawmidi cryptd rapl snd_seq snd_seq_device input_leds joydev snd_timer serio_raw snd vmw_vmci soundcore mac_hid sch_fq_codel vmwgfx drm_ttm_helper ttm drm_kms_helper drm msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid crc32_pclmul psmouse mptspi mptscsih mptbase ahci xhci_pci e1000 libahci scsi_transport_spi xhci_pci_renesas i2c_piix4 pata_acpi

